# How to replace NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I  have a feature called `smoking_status` it has 3 different values :

1) smokes

2) formerly smoked

3) never smoked

The feature column (smoking_status) has above 3 values as well as lot of `NaN` values how can I treat the `NaN` values because my data is not numerical, if it was numerical I could have replaced it using `median` or `mean`. How can I replace NaN values in my case ?

[image]

Comment: Replace with what?

Comment: This is off topic.  But I'd treat it as its own answer, a fourth category.

Comment: How to replace NaN values as the data is categorical and not numerical

Comment: @adi_tdkr So, you want ro teplace `NaN`s to some string?

Comment: There is no perfect answer to this question, but I'd recommend either giving the missing values the categorical value "unknown" or simply removing them altogether. If you make dummy variables, you can set the NaN values to be zero for all classes as well.

Comment: (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin Yes I want to know the method is it ok to replace the string ? or should I use label encoder directly on the feature.

Comment: Using label encoder with this variable is TOTALLY SENSELESS. You dont have ANY order relations between different smoking statuses. Go for one-hot encoding only (pd.get_dummies(df["smoking_status"]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be two better options than replacing `NaN` with `unknown` - at least in the context of a data science challenge which I think this is:

- replace this with the **most common value** (`mode`).
- **predict** the missing value using the data you have

Getting the most common value is easy. For this purpos you can use `<column>.value_counts()` to get the frequencies followed by a `.idxmax()` which gives you the index element from `value_counts()` with the highes frequency. After that you just call `fillna()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(['formerly', 'never', 'never', 'never', 
                   np.nan, 'formerly', 'never', 'never', 
                   np.nan, 'never', 'never'], columns=['smoked'])

print(df)
print('--')
print(df.smoked.fillna(df.smoked.value_counts().idxmax()))
```

Gives:

```
     smoked
0   formerly
1      never
2      never
3      never
4        NaN
5   formerly
6      never
7      never
8        NaN
9      never
10     never
--
0     formerly
1        never
2        never
3        never
4        never
5     formerly
6        never
7        never
8        never
9        never
10       never
```

Comment: Thanks got it. I think mode is good choice. But I could not understand the `Note` section how can I predict the missing data by buiding a separate model ?

Comment: @adi_tdkr I am assuming you're using this data set in order to predict cancer (or something like that) for a data science challenge? So, what you could do in the data pre-processing step is train a model that is able to predict whether somebody is smoking or not. This is very likely a better strategy than replacing tha NaNs just with the most common value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the data for those rows. You can simply fill it median or mean, most common value in that feature. But in this perticular case that's a bad idea considering the feature.

A better approach would be to fill with a string saying 'unknown'/'na'

```
df['smoking_status'].fillna('NA')
```

Then you can label encode it or convert the column to one hot encoding.

Comment: See the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @adi_tdkr what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question is about methodology, not technical issue.

So you can try

1) The most frequent value among those three;

2) Use some other categorical fields statistics of your dataset (e.g. group most common smoking status);

3) Random values;

4) "UNKNOWN" category

Then you can do one-hot-encoding and definitely check your models on cross-validation to chose the proper way.

Also there is more tricky way: use this status as a target variable and try to predict those NaNs with scikit using all other data.

Comment: Yes I want to learn methods and I do not have any issue. See the screenshot in my question.

Comment: You have to try different ways depending on your paticular dataset. Then you have to feed it into your models and chose the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Example categorical data:

```
ser = pd.Categorical(['non', 'non', 'never', 'former', 'never', np.nan])
```

Fill it:

```
ser.add_categories(['unknown']).fillna('unknown')
```

Gives you:

```
[non, non, never, former, never, unknown]
Categories (4, object): [former, never, non, unknown]
```